# What is the big-Oh runtime of two recursive O(logn) calls?

Tags: python, recursion, big-o, logarithm

```
def f(L):
    if len(L) < 1 billion:
        return L
    else:
        return f(L[:len(L) // 2]) + f(L[len(L) // 2:])
```

L is a list of size n

I know that if it was a single recursive call, then it would be O(logn), but there are two recursive calls here.

But it started to exhibit more of a O(n) runtime as I began to run it on a visualizer.

In my opinion it should be O(logn+logn) = O(2logn) = O(logn). Am I correct?

Comment: What kind of object is `L`?

Comment: it's just a list. I'll put that up there.

Comment: BTW, it should be quite a bit faster with a memoize decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider how many calls you're doing.  At the first level of the recursion you'll do 2 calls.  For each of those you'll do two more calls.  Etc ...  This means that at level `i` of the recursion you'll have made a total of `O(2^i)` function calls.

How many levels of the recursion are there?  This is just the height of a binary tree with `n` elements, which is `O(log_2 n)`.

So by the time you reach all the leaves of the recursion you will have done `O(2^(log_2 n)) = O(n)` function calls.

--

Another way of looking at it is that you eventually have to piece back together the entire list, so how could you possibly do that in less than `O(n)` time?

Comment: WOW this was super helpful! I was wondering how the O(n) got derived too. THANK YOU SO MUCH !

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm as it stands is going to be O(n) if `len(L)` is at least 1 billion because you will break the list into two, and then add the two halves back together. Both slicing and adding are O(n) operations.

If you want to test the runtime of the two recursive calls,

**1.** Pass in a start and end index, and call

```
f(L, start, start+(end-start)//2) + f(L, start+(end-start)//2, end)
```

**2.** Return `end-start` or some other O(1) value when `end-start` is less than 1 billion

Comment: oh thanks! I think I understand now.
O(logn) ignores half of the list if you integer divide it, but here I'm not ignoring the other half I divide. Thanks! (: